# Using same base form for different entity classes

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I'm currently working on a C# project where a main base form is derived by several other forms. Im using an entity class to handle data manipulation for every entity represented in the system: items, wharehouses, accounts, etc. That means that each of those derived forms is using its own kind of DAO.

I'm calling the base functionality from these derived forms just fine, what I'm strugling with right now is this: as each form has a different entity class I need a particular method for each derived class when the only difference between the base and the derived form is the type of entity class.

I have something like this:

```
        int id;
        int.TryParse(key.Text, out id);

        instance1 = adapter1.Populate(id);

        if (instance != null)
        {
            bindingSource.DataSource = instance1;
            this.GoEdit();
            this.MarkDeleted();
        }
```

So for example, what prevents me from using a generic version of this method to populate the entity class from my DB is that when defining those methods in the parent form I have to use the base class for my entities with no implementation so at the end I can't use a generic version.

Its bothering me that I have to copy this code over and over again (for each method of this kind) in the implementation of each derived form just to set the instance to the particular entity class. There should be another way and I hope anyone with a similar situation before could help me find a workaround..

Comment: Can you give more details on what instance1 and adapter1 are?

Comment: In my base form instance1 is the base entity class and adapter1 is the data-access class with all the update/insert/delete methods. I use the entity class as a map from the table fields just to manipulate data.. so the problem is that in my base form instance1 is referenncing the base class for all entities which is basically empty, I need a way to invoke the derived class for each one of the derived forms.

Answer (score 1):

How about putting a protected field in the base form to store a reference of the type of your base entity class.  The constructors of the derived forms could set this field to the appropriate derived entity class.  The code in your question could basically be just in the base form.

Comment: I tried that way but that member you mention in the base form should have a type, and that type must be your base entity class, so it turns out that when you invoke any specific method from the derived classes the empty method definition in the base class is the one being called..

Comment: Shouldn't be.  The whole point of inheritance (or one point, at least) is that an object of a derived type can be be assigned to a variable (or field in this case) of it's base type, and that member access would resolve to the member override in the most derived class in the inheritance chain.   So if `Foo` has a member `Bar`, and `DerivedFoo` inherits `Foo` and overrides `Bar`, then `Foo fooVar = new DerivedFoo(); fooVar.Bar();` would execute the `Bar()` method override declared in `DerivedFoo`.

Comment: I dont know why, maybe I'm missing something. But it has the virtual declaration on the base class.

Comment: The base method should be marked `virtual`, and the method in the derived class must have the same signature and be marked `override`.

Comment: I'm sorry to let this just hanging, crazy time at work.. anyway now I see where is the problem with the derived methods invocation: the signature is different for all of them. Each one is returning a particular type of entity instead of the base ECLASS type that was declared in the base class definition.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you might want to use an [interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  This would allow you to implement classes that inherit from that interface but implement their own functionality for the `Populate` function.

Say you have the class structure below:

```
interface iPopulate
{
   void Populate(int id);
}

class MyBaseClass
{
  //whatever
}

class Warehouse : MyBaseClass, iPopulate
{
   void Populate(int id)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Populate Warehouse");
   }
}

class Items : MyBaseClass, iPopulate
{
   void Populate(int id)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Populate Item");
   }
}
```

You would be able to populate the data for each without specifying what the inherited class is.  Example:

```
List<MyBaseClass> stuff = new List<MyBaseClass>();
stuff.Add(new Warehouse());
stuff.Add(new Items());
foreach(MyBaseClass i in stuff)
{
    int someId = 123;
    iPopulate pop = i as iPopulate;
    pop.Populate(someId);
}
```

This would output:

```
Populate Warehouse
Populate Item
```

Comment: Seems like a pretty good aproach, anyway my problem here is that each particular implementation of Populate() will be returning a different type of its own, because I'm using entity classes to encapsulate all data related to an entity.. 

For that reason i have one base return type for iPopulate() in the interface definition and a different derived type for each of the implementations.